# How do you power represent $\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, power-series

$f(x)=\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}$ how do you power represent this formula?

I tried it by dividing it into $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ but could not get a right answer.

Comment: Can you do $1/(1-x)^2$?

Comment: In case there is confusion, I meant expressing the form in a power series.

Comment: Should be $\frac{1}{x - 1} + \frac{ {\color{red}2}} {(x - 1)^2}$  First try to find the series for $\int \frac{1}{ (x - 1)^2 }$

Comment: what's the answer? @강승태

Comment: but the question is $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$ not $\frac{1}{x-1}$ the denominator is different.

Comment: yes I can do $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ fine. But once I have more than 1 in  numerator I am lost.

Comment: @강승태 If you can do $1/(1-x)^2$, surely you can do $x/(1-x)^2$?

Comment: Your wording "to power represent" is pretty ambiguous. Do you want the Laurent series around $x=1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1+x}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{x-1+2}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Yes I solved through partial fraction. But I did the partial fraction by plugging in numbers. Last time I tried partial fraction I got $\frac{A}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{B}{1-x}$. But could not find A and B, I found them only by stupidly plugging in numbers. Is there another formal procedure?

Comment: My bad. I did the partial fraction wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to obtain $(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^n$, either by the binomial formula or by differentiating $(1-x)^{-1}$. The final result is $\sum_{n\ge 0}(2n+1)x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

By using 
$\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ and [the Cauchy product of Power Series](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cauchy-product-of-power-series) you can get

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right)^2 =\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n $$
so 
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n+x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n+1} =   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)x^n$$